# Troubles installing the CAMELs library in python

Tags: python, clang, physics

Is anyone with a MacBook Pro able to do

`python -m pip install CAMELS-library`

in terminal without an error message because I have been trying to install this library for ages now? Thank you in advance!

Error message:

`Building wheel for Pylians (pyproject.toml) ... error error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Building wheel for Pylians (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully. │ exit code: 1 ╰─> [57 lines of output]

... clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp' error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1 [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip. ERROR: Failed building wheel for Pylians Failed to build Pylians ERROR: Could not build wheels for Pylians, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects`

Comment: 1) This seems to be tagged with gcc, but the output indicates you're using clang. Can you confirm whether you're using gcc or clang? 2) Have you tried the solution in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60043467/530160)?

Comment: I am using clang since this seems to be the default option when downloading and installing anaconda for Mac.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I tried it as described for the camels library but it still does not work.