# 'invalid option: --enable-cxx' after running 'brew install homebrew/science/hdf5 --enable-cxx'

Tags: c++, homebrew, openmp, hdf5

I'm trying to run a cpp file using Rcpp. The error that keeps popping up is clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'. After reading a bit, it seems to be the issue that I'm using Mac OS which does not include openmp with the default clang compiler. I've already installed llvm and libomp (following this post: [How to deal with "clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'" on travis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60005176/how-to-deal-with-clang-error-unsupported-option-fopenmp-on-travis)). But still the same error keeps popping up.

Now I tried to follow the approach by tractacus mentioned here https://github.com/velocyto-team/velocyto.R/issues/2. For this I try to install hdf5 with a link to C++ using the following line:

brew install homebrew/science/hdf5 --enable-cxx

It gives me the following error message 'invalid option: --enable-cxx'. I've also tried the option --with-cxx but that gives the same error message.

Does anyone know what the problem is here? Or knows any other way to solve the initial error of openmp not being linked to the clang compiler? Any help is much appreciated! I'm running this on Mac OS 12.5.

Comment: Hi Stan and welcome to StackOverflow and Rcpp.  I do not see how this has anything to do with Rcpp:  you are fighting macOS, and brew, and the fact that the R Project tells you to use their toolchain from the mac.r-project.org site. I think I should edit out the `rcpp` tag.

Comment: Hi Dirk, thanks a lot for your comment. Yes, I agree and edited it