# Fix "clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'" when building from source

Tags: clang, llvm, coin-or

I am currently working on something for which I need to use an application that I can only build from source (namely the [MiBS solver](https://github.com/coin-or/MibS))

When I do as described in the provided readme, I encounter this
`clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp' make[1]: *** [Master/main.o] Error 1 make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1`

I have read alot and found threads like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60005176/how-to-deal-with-clang-error-unsupported-option-fopenmp-on-travis), in which it is advised to use `brew install llvm libomp`and then use

```
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib omp_ProgramName.c -o ProgramName
```

My struggle with that is, I am not directly executing the compilation commands myself, rather they are hidden within the downloaded source.

I also tried
`brew install llvm libomp; export CC=/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang`
and then restarted my computer, as suggested in multiple threads.

That did not do anything.

Is there a way for me to leave the source code as is and just update clang or anything similar?

Thanks in advance and have a nice day!
Leon

Comment: the default clang on osx doesn't seem to support openmp. you can try updating clang to a newer version or install gcc instead

Comment: also, the `export` command only works within one command prompt session, so you must `export CC=/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang` every time before running the build command.

Comment: Thanks. I tried updating clang and and installing gcc, but that does not change what happens when the build tool calls clang. It seems like the clam command still leads to the "old" version.