# Install "Caret" package in R

Tags: r

```
> install.packages("caret")
also installing the dependencies ‘gower’, ‘recipes’

Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.6:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.6/PACKAGES'
Packages which are only available in source form, and may need compilation of
  C/C++/Fortran: ‘gower’ ‘caret’
Do you want to attempt to install these from sources? (Yes/no/cancel) yes
installing the source packages ‘gower’, ‘recipes’, ‘caret’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/gower_1.0.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 187590 bytes (183 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 183 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/recipes_1.0.9.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 827222 bytes (807 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 807 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/caret_6.0-94.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2274203 bytes (2.2 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.2 MB

* installing *source* package ‘gower’ ...
** package ‘gower’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include -fopenmp -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c R_register_native.c -o R_register_native.o
clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
make: *** [R_register_native.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘gower’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/gower’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘gower’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘gower’ is not available for package ‘recipes’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/recipes’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘recipes’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘recipes’ is not available for package ‘caret’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/caret’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘caret’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/gq/9kqnty1d5ms29x4gcyx3rn880000gn/T/Rtmp3QlE8K/downloaded_packages’
>
```

Can someone help me with this error? I have tried everything to install this package but nothing works (restarted, updated, typed the command). Please help.

Comment: perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/a/60043467/3358272?